# Obtaining references to all directives of a certain type up the component tree

Tags: angular

I have a complex scenario which I need help with.

I have a directive (called `TagDirective`) that is placed on multiple elements all over my app. I have another directive (`QueryDirective`) which needs to reference all instances of `TagDirective` that exist on its host element, as well as on all the elements above it in the hierarchy.

Example:

```html
<div appTag="a">
  <div appTag="b">
    <div appTag="c">
      <div appTag="d">
        <div appQuery>
          <!-- In here I want to have a reference to TagDirectives instances
              d,c,b,a -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div appTag="e">
      <div appTag="f">
        <div appTag="g">
          <div appTag="h">
            <div appQuery>
              <!-- In here I want to have a reference to TagDirectives instances
                  h,g,f,e,b,a -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div appQuery>
          <!-- In here I want to have a reference to TagDirectives instances
              f,e,b,a -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know I can obtain a reference to the `TagDirective` on the host element alone by having the injector provide it in the constructor of `QueryDirective`, I also know I can get the next higher instance by injecting `ViewContainerRef` and using its `parentInjector` member to request an instance of type `TagDirective`.

However, I haven't found a way to go further up the tree, and collect all the instances all the way up to the root.

How would I achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: I would do this with a service (declared inside providers array of directive). But actually I don't feel comfortable with your question, it is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: @n00dl3 that would mean that the service would mirror the component tree structure. I don't think I want to go that far, I mean, the tree structure is already there I just need to find a way to query it. Can you try to say exactly what needs to be clarified in the question?

Comment: Explaining why exactly you want to do this would help.

Comment: *the service would mirror the component tree structure.* No, the service would be created once per tree, you just register your directive to the service on init and unregister on destroy. this way you can maintain an array of your directives.

Comment: I added an example on what the expected results should be. Regarding the mirroring, each `TagDirective` would register itself along with its host component in the service. The service would have a data structure that associates each `TagDirective` instance with some element in the tree, so effectively, the service would know the entire tree structure (because it also needs to know elements in between two which have the tag)

Comment: Aaaaah I didn't think there were sibling `TagDirective` directives, my bad. Anyway, that was easier to understand with the code ;-).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since each of elements has its own injector we can't just use `multi: true` it will only work if we provide the same token on the same element.

Possible workaround could be as follows:

```typescript
export const TAG_DIRECTIVES_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('tags directives');

export function tagDirectiveFactory(dir: TagDirective, token: TagDirective[]) {
  return token ? [dir, ...token] : [dir];
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTag]',
  providers: [{
    provide: TAG_DIRECTIVES_TOKEN,
    useFactory: tagDirectiveFactory,
    deps: [TagDirective, [ new SkipSelf(), new Optional(), TAG_DIRECTIVES_TOKEN ]]
  }]
})
export class TagDirective  {}

@Directive({ 
  selector: '[appQuery]'
})
export class AppQueryDirective  {
  constructor(@Inject(TAG_DIRECTIVES_TOKEN) private directives: TagDirective[]){
      console.log(directives);
  }
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nb2fz3?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)**

In the code above i am providing `TAG_DIRECTIVES_TOKEN` on each of `div[appTag]` elements. I use factory with the following dependencies:

```typescript
deps: [TagDirective, [ new SkipSelf(), new Optional(), TAG_DIRECTIVES_TOKEN ]]
           ^^^^^                                            ^^^^^
current instance of TagDirective        parent optional TAG_DIRECTIVES_TOKEN
```

where:

- `SkipSelf` tells angular compiler to skip current token and use token that we provided in the parent `div[appTag]`
- `Optional` is used here because root `div[appTag]` element can't recognize parent `TAG_DIRECTIVES_TOKEN` so angular compiler won't raise the error:

> No provider for InjectionToken tags directives!

Comment: First of all, this works, thanks! But is there another approach in case the `TagDirective` is provided by a 3rd party library which I can't modify and does not include that particular provider scheme? Also, can you please elaborate a little bit about the `SkipSelf` and `Optional` parts? Those are new to me

Comment: In case when TagDirective is provided by a 3rd party library see this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mrjjn3?file=app/app.component.ts I just created MyTagDirective that provides us all tokens

Comment: BRILLIANT, you attach your own directive to any element which fits the other directive! thanks! :)

Comment: Yeah, that is. We can even get the same `@Inputs` in our directive

Comment: Why do you specify TAG_DIRECTIVES_TOKEN as a dependency? I'm amazed at how clueless I am about this...

Comment: I think I got it, the `deps` array specifies the arguments to the factory function, so first argument is our own instance, 2nd argument is the array we're building up, which will be provided to clients.

Comment: Because this way i have access to parent resolved token. Thiw works like reduce method in js, but it gathers providers from parent injector. Yes the TAG_DIRECTIVES_TOKEN is calculated on each of step