# Is there a way how to use Angular multi providers from all multiple levels?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am wondering whether it is possible to get the angular multi-providers from (ideally) all ancestors.

Lets say that I have a `INJECTION_TOKEN` `X` and I have a component structure like this:

```
<comp-a>
    <comp-b>
       <comp-c></comp-c>
    <comp-b>
<comp-a>
```

`comp-a` providers:
`providers: {provide: X, useValue: "A", multi: true}`

`comp-b` providers:
`providers: {provide: X, useValue: "B", multi: true}`

Is there a way how to get `["A", "B"]` in `comp-c` when I use Dependency injection like:

```
constructor(@Inject(X) obtainedArray:TypeOfX[]) {
    console.log(obtainedArray.length); //Expected to be 2
}
```

I have tried to use this provider in `comp-b` but it is throwing a cyclic DI expection:

```
providers:[
    {provide: X, useExisting: X, multi: true}
    {provide: X, useValue: "B", multi: true}
]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the following article states:

- [What you always wanted to know about Angular Dependency Injection tree](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-dependency-injection-and-tree-shakeable-tokens-4588a8f70d5d)

Angular stores providers on element by using **prototypical inheritance**. So, never mind whether you use `multi` or not you will get the following object that contains all providers on current element:

[image]

As you can see all providers are here, but since angular just [uses square brackets](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ce63dc6f954bcacd86f7ee0c401c1824f519b794/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L378-L387) to get provider from element you will get only nearest provider.

To workaround this you can use addition token that uses factory to collect all parent providers:

```typescript
import { Component, VERSION, InjectionToken, 
  Inject, SkipSelf, Optional } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <comp-a>
        <comp-b>
            <comp-c></comp-c>
        </comp-b>
    </comp-a>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { }

const X = new InjectionToken('X');

const XArray = new InjectionToken('XArray');

const XArrayProvider = {
  provide: XArray,
  useFactory: XFactory,
  deps: [X, [new SkipSelf(), new Optional(), XArray]]
};

export function XFactory(x: any, arr: any[]) {
  return arr ? [x, ...arr] : [x];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'comp-a',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  providers: [
    { provide: X, useValue: "A" },
    XArrayProvider
  ]
})
export class CompA { }


@Component({
  selector: 'comp-b',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  providers: [
    { provide: X, useValue: "B" },
    XArrayProvider
  ]
})
export class CompB { }


@Component({
  selector: 'comp-c',
  template: `{{ tokens }}`
})
export class CompC {
  constructor( @Inject(XArray) public tokens: any[]) { }
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/IpRjmtlg7posK49fa1rc?layout=1)**

Comment: @yurzui, this line of code `deps: [X, [new SkipSelf(), new Optional(), XArray]]` is little confusing. As dependency your pass new objects SkipSelf/Optional and XArray. Can you please describe it more detailed?

Comment: @Yerkon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805233/obtaining-references-to-all-directives-of-a-certain-type-up-the-component-tree/46808046#46808046

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do what you are trying to do with dependency injection, as far as I know. When you provide something in a component, it automatically hides previous providers with the same token. This is the way it is intended to work.

To achieve what you need, the only solution I can think of is to pass the providers as `inputs`.

I mean, `comp-a` declares a provider. `comp-b` also does it, but accepts an `input` containing a provider or array of providers. Then `comp-b` can add its own provider to the array and pass it as an input to `comp-c`.

I do not understand why exactly you want this, though ...

Comment: The use case if following:

We have a custom input component where we want to have an ability to type characters based on some RegEx (eg. only numbers). These RegExs are defined in a class with some additional info. The input itself get the list of those types using injector.

There are some default types which can be provided by input component itself (in the example it would be `comp-b`) but there is a possibility to implement your own type in outer component (in example it would be  `comp-a`).